# Cannot access property in tableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, properties

I have some custom tableviewcells, each with a thumbnail having a gesture recognizer on it, to open a modal box.

In each tableviewcell there's a property containing a string.

In the method called by the gesture recognizer, i'm trying to access this property, by looping the superviews of the gesture recognizer.

```
 - (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)LongPressGestureRecognizer
 {
    //handle press
    ZoomImageViewController *zoomImage = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"zoomImage"];

    UIView *subview = LongPressGestureRecognizer.view;
    while (![subview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell self]] && subview) {
        subview = subview.superview;
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)subview;

    zoomImage.filename = cell.machinePicture;
    zoomImage.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self presentViewController:zoomImage animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

In debugger the cell object is the tableviewcellcontroller containing the property i want to access.
However, on the following line i get the error "Property 'machinePicture' not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell *'"

```
zoomImage.filename = cell.machinePicture;
```

I don't get why the property cannot by found, while cell seems to be the correct object i'm looking for, containing the property i want...

Comment: Are you using a custom cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard `UITableViewCell` does not contain a `machinePicture` property, did you extend the `UITableViewCell` class?

Use that custom class instead, casting accordingly:

```
MyUITableViewCell *cell = (MyUITableViewCell *)subview;
```

Answer (score 0):

on `UITableviewCell` you wont be getting a property `machinePicture` since it is not a property in `UITableViewCell`. I think you are using a custom table view cell. So you must typecast it. Secondly you must use `tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method of `UITableViewDelegate` to get the tableviewcell and not using gesture recognizer.